# Should I resign in between illness (recuperating on leave)

Tags: new-job, resignation, notice-period, sickness

I'm currently on leave from my company as I'm recovering from a severe bout of dengue. Yesterday, I appeared for an interview with another company which has made me an offer I want to accept. Should I immediately inform my earlier company and resign via email/call ? Or should I wait to recover and join back and then resign, after about 1 week.

And I need to join the new company within about 40 days.

I intend to leave my current company which has a notice period of 30 days, as soon as they can release me, even if by paying notice period shortfall, but on amicable terms. Even if I resign today, I plan to attend for about 2 weeks to finish off the remainder of my latest assignment

Comment: The notice period is 30 days, but why do you say you will only attend for about 2 weeks? Do you intend not to fully fulfill your notice?

Comment: Resigning when you are officially on sick leave is going to look suspicious.

Comment: I have the option of paying salary to company in lieu of partial notice period service. And the current job is in a different city, where it's expensive for me to stay, and my rent agreement there also is on a monthly renewal basis, so it benefits me to leave before month end.

Comment: You might want to change your phrasing from "should I do X (resign now) or Y (resign later)" to instead focusing on what the company might think of you doing X (if that's what you want to know). We ultimately can't make the decision between X and Y for you, and there are factors to consider (such as the financial side) which are beyond the scope of this site, but we can advise on a specific part of it.

Comment: your still working when on sick leave so whats the issue put in your resignation as if you where not on sick leave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is not always possible, it is good to leave any employment on amicable terms with the employer. One thing you could do is resign now over email stating that your earlier efforts at job hunting has materialized and you are moving to your own city back. Offer them to convert your medical leave into leave without pay. Join after 1 week, talk to HR to buyout your last 1 week of notice, complete your job in 2 weeks and leave with balance pay of 2 weeks and buyout.

This way, no one can actually ask you any questions, you did not work you did not accept pay, you finished your work in 2 weeks, you bought out 1 week of your notice period as per company policy and left.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's actually putting into words a lot of relevant ideas. Also, I have actually exhausted medical leaves due to this illness, it was already leave without pay, I thought mentioning that will complicate an already difficult problem statement.

Comment: why would the OP do this no sane person would take this course of action

Answer (score 3):

So you attended at least one interview while you were notionally too sick to return to work...

Your employer will of course point this out to you if you resign now.  It therefore makes sense to resign when you're officially back at work again.

You could of course return to work early, but this will also raise questions.

Comment: This. Attending an interview while you're on sick leave is almost certainly misconduct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am still in bed rest, attending the interview was a very difficult process for me. Everyone in the family had to chip in for help - driving, carrying my documents and all. If I'd not attended I'd have missed the chance. And I'm in no position to join work till about a week from now.

Comment: Your current employer may not see things as clearly.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: An interview during sick leave is not necessarily misconduct. There is a [German court case](https://www.kanzlei-flaemig.de/vorstellungsgespraech-waehrend-der-krankheit-kuendigungsgrund/) about exactly this, and the court ruled that an interview during sick leave is ok as long as attending it does not prolong  the illness or hurt recovery. You don't have to stay in bed all day just because you're on sick leave...